# linear layout error resource android:layout_width

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, resources

please help i am new to android apps, and i was following the guide that is on the android developers site, but when i want to run the code iam getting and error "no resource identifier found for attribute layout_width...

here is a copy of the xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:Layout_weight="1"
    android:Layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:Layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>



<Button 
    android:Layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:Layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/button_send" />
```

Comment: its `layout` not `Layout`

Comment: use ths android:layout_width="wrap_content"  as @Raghunandan says

Comment: I think there is typo in your `EditText` and `Button`. Used `android:layout_width` in small letters

Answer (score 1):

XML is case sensitive. You have capital Ls in your code, it should be this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:Layout_weight="1"
    android:Layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:Layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>



<Button 
    android:Layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:Layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/button_send" />

<LinearLayout/>
```

Comment: i have changed to lower case and this is the message i am getting now Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'Layout_height' in package 
  'android'
 - The markup in the document following the root element must be well-
  formed.
 - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'Layout_width' in package 
  'android'